# Sort columns to find errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of numbers which need to be in ascending order. If not then, it must be highlighted so that it can be corrected. I've a simple excel working for it but need a macro. But here's the catch, whenever I try to write the code, it compares the last value of nth column with 1st value of n+1 column, which i don't want. Here's example for ref:

```
25  30  35  40  44  48
65  75  85  95  105 115
```

So it's comparing 48 with 65. Kindly help.Also, there are other columns like date,name,address in between these numbers. So i don't know if For loop would work. Data is as follows:

Data in [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6-Dmx4gmQGJWbCDi14OyfiThMO-KA_gHvbUiN2Gky8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Show us some code then we can help you better.

Comment: You can do this with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Hi! I tried doing it with conditional formatting but it doesn't work. It wasn't highlighting correct cells. Sorry, but I haven't written any code since i'm clueless about this problem.